# Generate srvs from directory using catkin build

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For srv generation, I've taken to using `add_service_files(DIRECTORY srv)` instead of listing each file individually, since it's more compact and I don't ever put srvs in that directory that I don't want generated.

However, one downside is, since you don't have to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file when you add a new srv to that directory, it doesn't generate them unless I do a `catkin clean` or I make some edit to `CMakeLists.txt`.

What I want to know, is there a way to force it to generate the srvs with a `catkin build` without having to do a clean, and without making bogus edits to `CMakeLists.txt`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297835/generate-srvs-from-directory-using-catkin-build/) by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 642 on 2018-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With `catkin build` you can trigger an explicit CMake configure invocation by passing `--force-cmake` (see `catkin build --help`).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1